# CPU Affinity in Boost::Thread API

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, cpu, boost-thread

Is it possible to set CPU affinity in boost threads ((i.e. setting each thread to run on a different CPU)? Is there any tutorial/documentation you can suggest on this? Googling does not return much info except the following thread where the specified example (boost-bind_processor.v1.tar.gz) is no longer present in the file server. Thanks.

http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2009/02/45172.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just don't. Most of the time when you think this will help things, it just makes them worse.

Every restriction you place on the system has a cost. The scheduler is very smart and the more restrictions you force on it, the worse it will perform. The scheduler will not move a thread from one core to another unless it has a good reason.

Comment: The boost API has a method named native_handle which returns the underlting posix thread. I preformed the required setting on the underlying posix thread.

Comment: I agree, don't do this for the normal applications.

However, you might be writing a high performance service on a NUMA platform (which is basically every platform now). In which case it can be a win to set the processor affinity for some threads. You want to do network reads/writes from the node nearest the PCI bus with the NIC on it, etc. 

That said, yes, there is a high cost; it's in your time & labor. You have to tune for specific hardware configurations and run regressions anytime the underlying hardware changes or drivers get updated or the OS gets patched.

Answer (score -2):

In case of .NET apps, you probably need to look into something called `ProcessorAffinity`.

[MSDN 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processoraffinity.aspx)
[MSDN 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity)

Comment: I am working in linux and using GNU compiler but thanks anyway.